# Which 2-sample univariate t-test to use?

Tags: t-test

X1 is wing length, X2 is tail length for 45 male and 45 female bugs.
Which 2-sample univariate t-test should I use? 
My thought was to use Hotelling's T-square?
But Hotelling's is multi-variate not univariate. Now, I'm not sure...

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question you want to answer? Do you want to compare males to females, or wing length to tail length, or something else? And why are you restricted to a univariate test?

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, when there are two explanatory variables and both have just two levels, we have the famous two-by-two contingency table. Fisher’s exact test can take such a matrix as its sole argument. Alternatively you can use Pearson’s chi-squared test.

If your null hypothesis is not the 25:25:25:25 distribution across the four categories (i.e. say it's 9:3:3:1), you'll have to calculate the expected frequencies explicitly.

Then perform the chi-squared test (in R) like that:

```
chisq.test(observed,p=c(9,3,3,1),rescale.p=TRUE)
# rescale.p is needed because the probabilities do not sum to 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

While your questions is not clear (which means do you want to compare?) you can consult the wiki: [Comparing Means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparing_means) to decide what to do.

Comment: I'm testing individual component means

Comment: I'm restricted to unvariate t-tests.

Comment: What do you mean by individual components? What are these 'components'? Ideally, you should edit the question to clarify so that others can also post appropriate answers. See also Aniko's comments to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need to clarify your question.

However, I'm guessing that you want to determine if wing length or tail length differ between male and female bugs. In this case I would just do a couple of [two sample t-tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_two-sample_t-test). So for wing length you would have the following hypothesis:

```
H_0: wing length does not depend on gender
H_1: wing length differs by gender.
```

You would have something similar for tail length.

Comment: i need to compare tail length male vs tail length female and in a separate test compare wing length male vs wing length female.

Ho: X1-male = X1-female
H1: not equal

and

Ho: X2-male = X2-female
H1: not equal

I thinking 2 separate univariate t-tests?

Comment: That's what my answer describes.

Comment: In R:

##X1 TEST

t.test(T6.11.dat[1],T5.12.dat[1])

RIGHT?

Comment: @Matt: that's correct